# Convert horizontal array to vertical one in Julia

Tags: julia

assume I have a 3-element array like this:

```
A = [1, 2, 3]
```

How can I convert it to:

```
B = [1; 2; 3]
```

in Julia?

Comment: `transpose` or `\``

Comment: The two expressions you have are exactly equal to each other, `[1, 2, 3] == [1; 2; 3]`. They both represent one-dimensional vectors. In Julia, one-dimensional vectors are different from row-vectors and column-vectors.

Comment: By the way, @OscarSmith's comment appears to have a typo. The character used for `transpose` is `'` (comma), not backtick.

Comment: oops. sorry for the typo

Comment: Also interesting `reshape([1,2,3],1,3)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`transpose` creates an `Adjoint` object that actually holds a view

```
julia> A = [1, 2, 3];

julia> A'
1×3 LinearAlgebra.Adjoint{Int64,Array{Int64,1}}:
 1  2  3
```

Wrapping it with collect would make an actual horizontal vector:

```
julia> collect(A')
1×3 Array{Int64,2}:
 99  2  3
```

You need to however understand that in Julia 1-dimensional `Vector`s are always vertical while a vector can be also represented by a two-dimensional matrix where one dimension is equal to one:

```
julia> B=[1 2 3]
1×3 Array{Int64,2}:
 1  2  3

julia> C = collect(B')
3×1 Array{Int64,2}:
 1
 2
 3
```

Finally, each of those can be converted to a standar vector using the `vec` function or `[:]` operator:

```
julia>  A == B[:] == C[:] == vec(B) == vec(C) == @view(C[:]) == @view(B[:])
true
```